# Intent Chooser does not disapper on single click

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am creating an android app in which i have LISTVIEW on main screen. The LISTITEM associated with the LISTVIEW contains an IMAGEVIEW(Share Icon). Onclick event of LISTITEM i am trying to display intent chooser for sharing contents of LISTITEM, but my problem is that, If i don't perform any action on INTENT chooser displayed on screen and if i simply try to press hardware back button, this currently displayed intent chooser doesn't go away, it remain on screen. After several attempts by pressing back button, it disappears after 3-4 attempts. I actually don't want this unusual behavior, it should vanish on first attempt.

```
        public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        var item = items [position];
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.HadithListViewItem, null);


        string HadithText = string.Empty;
        string BookName = string.Empty;
        string ChapterName = string.Empty;


        view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.HadithText).Text = items [position].HadithText;


        HadithText = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.HadithText).Text;

        BookName = items[position].BookName;;
        ChapterName = items[position].ChapterName.ToString()+ "-" + items[position].HadithID.ToString();



        ImageView share = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.ShareButton);

        share.Click += (object sender2, EventArgs e2) => {;

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend); 
            sharingIntent.SetType("text/plain");


            String shareBody = HadithText;
            sharingIntent.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, BookName + "(" + ChapterName + ")\n");
            sharingIntent.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, shareBody);
            this.context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));


        };


        view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.HadithBook).Text = BookName;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.HadithChapter).Text = ChapterName;
        view.SetOnClickListener (null);



        return view;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're setting the Click multiple times. I suspect if you change the click to equals, it should work right, only launching a single instance of onClick. To test for it, try logging something out in the Click routine.

```
share.Click = (object sender2, EventArgs e2)
```

Comment: + sign is mandatory... it shows compilation error with out + and also i am adding it only once.